# Xamarin - How do i display a pdf file from ftp server in forms

Tags: xamarin

I have to display a pdf file from FTP server in Xamarin on iOS and Android.
Not able to display the downloaded file, I am okay to display it within the App or OS default viewer.

Comment: You can use a WebView and display within the app. Or use any third party PDF viewer. If its a downloaded then the download manager would take care of it and opening the corresponding application. You can also use AppLinks and open it as well.

Comment: Here is a [Xamarin tutorial to display a PDF in a WebView](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/display-pdf/). You would have to download the PDF from your FTP server first.

Answer (score 1):

the most easy way is to save this file to your device local storgae and use Xamarin Web View to display it.

it is very easy , you can find step by step on this article:

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/display-pdf/